# CCD IK Pole Target Contraint

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I am writing my own CCD IK solver. The version I have currently works perfectly fine, however, I need a way to make it use a pole target constraint.

What I want is for the elbow of my characters arm to point towards a pole target, similar to how Blender allows you to add a pole target.

I would love if someone could point me in the right direction of how this can be implemented.

Comment: You might be able to expand the audience of folks who can answer if you elaborate a bit on the how a "pole target" behaves, in case the reader is unfamiliar with the Blender implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never wrote CCD solver with pole targets but I've played quite a lot with FABRIK algorithm and I may have some idea to try.

Just before you run your solver try to rotate entire IK chain towards you pole target and then run the CCD. This should move you IK computations to the plane containing chain start, chain target and pole target.

As I've said I don't know if this will work so please let me know if you try it :).

Comment: Jesus, it really was that simple...
https://gph.is/2PJg9Iy

Comment: Great to hear that, thanks for the info. BTW: For chains with only 2 bones there're analytical IK solutions that should be simpler to compute and more stable.